# How to also display the values within the bucket that considered during aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to aggregate records based on the created_date. So based on each created date, there are group of records right?. Now, Could someone tell me how to display the created date as well along with each set of results.?

```
 "aggs": {
    "by_created_date": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "createddate"
      },
     _source["createddate"] //Something like this. so that i can see what date it has used.

      "aggs": {
       ....
      }, //Also may need to use some aggregation on this level.
   },
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more by adding a sample document, response and mapping that you have. Terms aggregation already shows you the date in the `key_as_string` field when you do terms on a `date` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
aggs":{
    "by_created_date":{
        "terms":{
            "field":"createddate.keyword",
            "size":1000
        },
        "aggs":{
            "bucket" : {
                "terms" : { 
                    "field" : "field_name",
                    "size": 10
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`terms` is used for grouping a field.

So, for nested grouping...you have to write nested aggregation like upper code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please provide an explanation to supplement the code you posted? What did you change and how does it fix the OP's issue?